# Getting Name/ID of mouse-hovered Items/buttons/folders globally for Windows

Tags: c#, mousehover

What I am trying to do is to trigger mouse click by hovering on items. 
If the mouse stay on an item/button/folder long enough without going out, it will trigger mouse click.
I have done the mouse click triggering part.
The problem now is to detect whether the mouse cursor is still on the same item or has it gone out of it.
I have tried using user32.dll to extract information but it doesn't work for all items, e.g. items within folders and buttons in applications.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetDlgCtrlID(IntPtr hwndCtl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(int xPoint, int yPoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    public static int GetHoveredControlID(int xPoint, int yPoint)
    {
        return GetDlgCtrlID(WindowFromPoint(xPoint, yPoint));
    }
```

Comment: Does WindowFromPoint return a valid value?  Can't you just use that?

Comment: It only returns different value for different windows. So I can't use it for icons, folders and buttons.